# Asp.net Core Web Api Multiple Controller Method For Get All

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller which gets data from a database but i want to have multiple methods `[Actions]` for the same `GetAll` Method based on different key.

**Example**

consider this DB

[image]

can i have a controller with different `GetAll` method based on `CountryID`, `AddressID`, `DepartmentID` like this

```
   [ApiController]
    [Route("api/Users")]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
      //Without a key
         [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
        {
            return repository.GetAll();
        }

         [HttpGet("{addressId}")]
        public async IEnumerable<User> GetAll([FromRoute]string addressId)
        {
            User user=  repository.GetAll(addressId);
         }

         [HttpGet("{CountryID}")]
        public async IEnumerable<User> GetAll([FromRoute]string CountryID)
        {
            User user=  repository.GetAll(CountryID);
         }

         [HttpGet("{DepartmentID }")]
        public async IEnumerable<User> GetAll([FromRoute]string DepartmentID ) 
        {
            User user=  repository.GetAll(DepartmentID );
         }

    }
```

and if i can how can i call this different method from the http request.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use ViewModel to filter data? A ViewModel that contains CountryID, AddressID and DepartmentID .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define routing rules like below:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    // Without a key
    [HttpGet]
    // GET /api/Users
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet("AddressId/{id}")]
    // GET /api/Users/AddressId/123
    public IEnumerable<User> GetByAddressIdAll([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        ....
    }

    [HttpGet("CountryId/{id:int}")]
    // GET /api/Users/CountryId/456
    public IEnumerable<User> GetByCountryIdAll([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        ....
    }

    [HttpGet("DepartmentID/{id:int}")]
    // GET /api/Users/DepartmentId/678
    public IEnumerable<User> GetByDepartmentIdAll([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

See the documentation: [Attribute routing with Http verb attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#verb6)